# Transpose a 3x3 matrix across the anti-diagonal

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a program which takes a 3x3 matrix on stdin and prints its transpose along the anti-diagonal to stdout. You may assume that all elements of the matrix will be integers. Columns are space-separated and rows are newline-separated.

#### Example

Input:

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
3 5 3
2 4 2
1 3 1
```

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
9 6 3
8 5 2
7 4 1
```

Comment: Your example output seems incorrect; it has only been transposed along the second diagonal.

Comment: Also, what are the matrix elements? Digits? Positive integers? Any integers? Floats? Any strings? If numbers, is there an upper limit?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen edited

Comment: So, you're effectively saying that the matrix should be transposed *twice* along the first diagonal (once in step 1, then again in step 2) as well as along the second diagonal (in step 2)? That's the only way I can make sense of your example output.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen well yes

Comment: Your first answer has a symmetry so it's easier to perform the transformation. My code works on this example but not on the second one.

Comment: What if the language of choice uses newline to mark end of input? Is `[1 2 3; 3 4 5; 1 2 3]` an acceptable input format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## APL - 7

```
⌽⍉⌽3 3⍴
```

Example input:

```
⌽⍉⌽3 3⍴1 2 3 3 4 5 1 2 9
> 9 5 3
  2 4 2
  1 3 1
```

[ngn APL demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%u233D%u2349%u233D3%203%u23741%202%203%203%204%205%201%202%209)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain themself? Thanks.

Comment: God love APL. Nice solution!

Comment: @mniip ANy chance you can explain how this works? It's so... concise! I love it!

Comment: `3 3⍴` converts input to a 3x3 matrix. `⌽` reverses it along first dimension, `⍉` transposes it, and then `⌽` reverses it again.

Comment: Why do you need to include `3 3⍴`? Let the program take a matrix as input. Also, this isn't a program or function, but rather just a snippet.

Comment: Function (4 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS) in Dyalog Unicode): `⌽∘⍉⌽`, Full program (4): `⌽⍉⌽⎕`, Full program (8, raveled input): `⌽⍉⌽3 3⍴⎕`.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 20 bytes

```
(r=Reverse)[r@#]&
```

The `` is Mathematica's transpose operator (which is displayed as a superscript T in Mathematica).

Answer (score 4):

### Sage, 39

<sup>*Runs in the interactive prompt*</sup>

```
matrix(input()[::-1]).transpose()[::-1]
```

Sample input:

```
[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[1,2,3]]
```

Sample output:

```
[3 5 3]
[2 4 2]
[1 3 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript, 18 / 15 / 11 chars

```
~]-1%3/zip{' '*n}%
```

This is the straightforward implementation, following pretty much the exact steps given in the question.  There's a clever arithmetic trick one could use instead, but it turns out to need more characters.

Sample input:

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
1 2 9
```

Sample output:

```
9 5 3
2 4 2
1 3 1
```

Ps. If I can use the same output format as in [ace's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24895) (i.e. extra with square brackets around each row), I can save three chars for a total of **15 chars**:

```
~]-1%3/zip{`n}%
```

If a one-line output format like `[[9 5 3] [2 4 2] [1 3 1]]` is allowed, I can shrink that further to just **11 chars**:

```
~]-1%3/zip`
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, I think you misinterpreted the question. For the matrix `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, your program should output `[[9,6,3],[8,5,2],[7,4,1]]`, not `[[3,6,9],[2,5,8],[1,4,7]]`.

Comment: @ace: Yeah, I noticed that. Stupid symmetric example. Fixed.

Comment: You may save one character in each of the first two cases if you include the newline in the map, e.g. `{' '*n}%`.

Comment: @Howard: Edited, thanks! That'll give me an extra blank line at the end of the output, but I suppose that's acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## J - 16 (?) char

Taking the 3x3 matrix as a grid from stdin, we get the 16 character:

```
|:&.|.".1!:1]3#1
```

This can be made shorter if the input is made more flexible, as in the Sage and APL answers:

```
|:&.|.".1!:1]1   NB. if stdin input form can be  1 2 3, 4 5 6,: 7 8 9
|:&.|.           NB. if used as an expression like the APL answer
```

The key is in the `|:&.|.` portion: this is what transposes the matrix. It reads *Transpose* (`|:`) *Under* (`&.`) *Reverse* (`|.`), meaning you reverse the matrix, transpose it, and then undo your initial reverse.

Demo:

```
   |:&.|.".1!:1]3#1          NB. three lines input, three output
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
9 6 3
8 5 2
7 4 1

   1 2 3,3 4 5,:1 2 9        NB. a matrix
1 2 3
3 4 5
1 2 9
  |:&.|. 1 2 3,3 4 5,:1 2 9  NB. the logic
9 5 3
2 4 2
1 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## K, 3/7/20(?) bytes

K is similar enough to APL that a character-for-character transliteration of @mniip's solution works:

```
|+|3 3#
```

In action:

```
  |+|3 3#1 2 3 3 4 5 1 2 9
(9 5 3
 2 4 2
 1 3 1)
```

This behaves identically, modulo the way output is prettyprinted. However, I should note that neither this solution nor the solution it is based on actually operate on `stdin`/`stdout`. To implement this as per a stricter interpretation of the spec in Kona-compatible K3 it's necessary to use `0:` and jump through some hoops:

```
`0:,/'2$|+|3 3#. 0:`
```

Write to stdout (`` `0: ``) the join over each (`,/'`) of the two-wide string format (`2$`) of the anti-diagonal transpose (`|+|`) of the 3x3 reshape (`3 3#`) of the eval (`.`) of stdin (`` 0:` ``).

In action:

```
indigo:kona je$ ./k antidiag.k 
K Console - Enter \ for help

  1 2 3 3 4 5 1 2 9
 9 5 3
 2 4 2
 1 3 1
```

There's a pretty good reason that APL-family programmers tend to avoid problems that force the use of stdin/stdout. Arguably, with flexible IO requirements, this could be solved with simply `|+|`:

```
  |+|(1 2 3;3 4 5;1 2 9)
(9 5 3
 2 4 2
 1 3 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
RÞTR
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=R%C3%9ETR&inputs=%5B%5B9%2C6%2C3%5D%2C%5B8%2C5%2C2%5D%2C%5B7%2C4%2C1%5D%5D&header=&footer=)

```
R    # Vectorised reverse
 ÞT  # Transpose
   R # Vectorised reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) `-c`, 2628 bytes

```
(()()()()){({}[()]<{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<>)<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<>)<>>)}{}(<>({})<>){(({}))((()()()()()){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}(<>({})<>)({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<><>{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}{(({}))((()()()()()){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}{}{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<>)<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}<>{(({}))((()()()()()){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<>)<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}([(((()()())()){}{}){}]{}){(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<>){(({}))((()()()()()){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>({}<>)<>(()()){({}[()]<{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<>)<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<>)({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}<>{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>{(({}))((()()()()()){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<>)<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<>)({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}<>([]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}<>(()()()){({}[()]<{(({}))((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])((){[()](<{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}){{}(<(<()>)>)}{}}{}({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}
```

If it weren't for IO requirements this could have been 842 bytes but hey it was a good challenge :P I'm sure there's a lot that can be golfed here and I will see if I can find some of those spots later but right now I need to stop staring at brackets.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VTNCsMgDL7vKTwmhx7634L4IsVDNxiMjR12FZ/dmVpsN7YdVkultfiTxC9fQszx0V/uyfnWX40BQDdQgdIdoOQK7A4R6PNKPf5kpLS0WlRkDVxpK@MCuRCoycgKuB0ocBDoNwPggvCtYHKEc0ffXAB0Erma4Oisae@wufAhvDj8RcxzWeaANH8kbYWIts/pnEOoAprnd7O4wj@LzmM5sAFL0hxJNTm7CN7pIlh/IUCfiy64YVmrZS@jFkuC42ESKp876oG7qjPC@HRt7D077T7GpGnKsixjeZ4fiqJgZVmyqqoOdV2zpmlY27YmOT0B)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes

```
⌽˘⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://bqnpad.mechanize.systems/s?bqn=eyJkb2MiOiJpbiDihpAgM%2BKAvzPipYpbMSwgMiwgMywgMywgNCwgNSwgMSwgMiwgM11cbm91dCDihpAgM%2BKAvzPipYpbMywgNSwgMywgMiwgNCwgMiwgMSwgMywgMV1cblxu4oy9y5jijL1pblxuXG5vdXRcbuKAolNob3cg4oy9y5jijL1pbiIsInByZXZTZXNzaW9ucyI6W10sImN1cnJlbnRTZXNzaW9uIjp7ImNlbGxzIjpbXSwiY3JlYXRlZEF0IjoxNjc1MDA1ODcxMzM1fSwiY3VycmVudENlbGwiOnsiZnJvbSI6MCwidG8iOjk4LCJyZXN1bHQiOm51bGx9fQ%3D%3D)

#### Explanation

```
⌽˘⌽
  ⌽ 1. Reverse over [leading axis][1]
⌽˘  2. Reverse over "major cells"
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 15 bytes

Rotate the matrix 180 degrees, and transpose it. This takes the input where columns are space separated and rows are newline separated. Outputs on the same format.

```
@(A)rot90(A,2)'

ans([1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9])

ans =

     9     6     3
     8     5     2
     7     4     1
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Racket, 42 bytes

```scheme
(λ(m[r reverse])(r(apply map list(r m))))
```

Takes a list of lists of numbers as input, and outputs the same type.

Thought I might as well find a use case for some of the tips I'd written up some years ago!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY07DsIwEET7nGIkmt0iBSH8zoIorGRBFrZjrRdQzsYduFJIKJCYakZPeqOuu4lNq@DSFfodVUW9XHwSmLpU8lCkdsn8RO8XxZNC5SFa5Myk5HIOI6LLCL4YKSLPmXiWZBWzsc7qk9XdEO4xFTQt/8hTvQno/wWk4vrFQbRGgw1XoBZb7JayxwFH5g8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.94 bytes

```
.rZt.r
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbL9IqiSvSKIByo2IKd0dGGOkY6xrE60cY6JjqmQBrCj4UoAAA)

`.r` reverses each row; `Zt` transposes; `.r` reverses each row.

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 87 <s>98</s> <s>101</s> bytes

```fortran
integer A(3,3);read*,((A(i,j),j=1,3),i=1,3);print'(3i3)',((A(4-i,4-j),i=1,3),j=1,3)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBDoIwEIThu08xN7Zke8Ctimk88CgkFLI9FLPh/QuinubP5JtX22wsfpm/UauWLS3JMJCwuGhpnFomGkg5O86v7nhZz4lvO3RDouKa0wSvHHz@gx@PqUy1Ah1wBQQXIAA34P7JB9ADT@w)
  <s><sub>[98b](https://tio.run/##NYs7DoMwEAV7TvE61tG6IOv8QBQcBckGraWYyOH@DiGkeiO9mWnJax6TnacflKJpDXPI7PUZ0luXRMJi2nbochj9iYkGUo6GY99sB@s@1StvYU2iYurdcVbZ2fgXDr0LyZcCNMAZEFSAAy7A9Ys34A488AE)</sub></s>
<s><sub>[101bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzNDoMwDIPvfYoc2ykcuu6XigOPgpSAUmntFHj/rjAutmV/8lx00yl3y/wPtUreeGFFkg/nVUq2AYPr@zEqT3RBa0crmBymwbcB5TBDBdIQ0GPn41fbSSNPUM7eRc5EZddaPVwhgLnBHR5gnvCCN/wA)</sub></s>

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 83 <sup><s>97</s></sup> bytes

> -14 bytes thanks to @noodleman !

Input and output are the matrixes exactly in the string format specified by OP.

This surely is the shortest JS answer using this format!

```javascript
s=>s.split(/\s/).map((e,i,a)=>a[i+(2-i%3-(i/3|0))*4]+(i%3<2?` `:i>6?``:`
`)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NTsMwEEb3PsUoEpJN/qidhjbCyUEo0lipi1yFJKqdigVbdhwBLteLhKGlEgtmM6M3M@/bm6Px7cGNIe2HrZ13eva69pkfOxd4vvG5yF7MyLlNXGKErs2ji7lM3Y1KucvV250Qt8VTzAk8yAYBK1eXDWKFDIXI9oPrEWd7NN1kgtXc9eMUEvs62jbYbXKwfuqC3l24oIB26P3Q2awbnjn/XWt9fWii0@f7po@q6PT1QV3ElxPB2DWDM1yABMUUFLBk5xlZwlDBkqgkKokqWCCjt795UfpT0X8yUkHJ7mEF67NsDSXRFVFJtDjL5m8)

---

Let me explain a bit:
First we split the input string on all whitespaces, which gives us a **`one-dimensional array`**.

Then, we switch each item with their corresponding targets by transforming the current value of the (one-dimensional) index this way:
**`i+(2-i%3-(i/3|0))*4`**.

And finally, we concatenate all the elements while adding the   and `\n` after the right items (but specifically not after the last item).

Comment: Replace the whole `.split .join .split` thing with `.split(/\s/)` to save 14 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NTsMwEEb3PsUoEpJN/qidhjbCyUEo0lipi1yFJKqdigVbdhwBLteLhKGlEgtmM6M3M@/bm6Px7cGNIe2HrZ13eva69pkfOxd4vvG5yF7MyLlNXGKErs2ji7lM3Y1KucvV250Qt8VTzAk8yAYBK1eXDWKFDIXI9oPrEWd7NN1kgtXc9eMUEvs62jbYbXKwfuqC3l24oIB26P3Q2awbnjn/XWt9fWii0@f7po@q6PT1QV3ElxPB2DWDM1yABMUUFLBk5xlZwlDBkqgkKokqWCCjt795UfpT0X8yUkHJ7mEF67NsDSXRFVFJtDjL5m8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @noodleman Oh wow, thank you! I really should learn about regex, i never think about it!

Comment: Well since you don't know, `\s` matches any whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 78

```
write.table(matrix(rev(unlist(strsplit(readLines(),' '),' ')),3),qu=F,r=F,c=F)
# Copy and paste the input
# If the prompt is not on a new line, press `enter` after the last line
# Type `Ctrl+D`
```

I discovered the `rev()` function on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497058/2257664), it helped me to understand than the transformation is just reversing the input and putting it in the matrix from top to bottom, and left to right.

I also discovered that the argument `row.names=T` (T for `true`) can be shortened to `r=T`, saving 16 chars.

### Explanations:

- `readLines()` reads STDIN and return a vector with 3 elements (each one is a string)
- `strsplit()` splits the strings in the vector by using space as a separator
- `unlist()` makes a flat list from a vector
- `rev()` puts the list in reverse order
- `matrix([list], 3)` creates a matrix from the list, the argument `3` indicates that there is 3 elements per row
- `write.table([matrix], qu=F, r=F, c=F)` prints the matrix without quotes, rows and columns labels

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, 50

```
Input A:rowSwap(A,1,dim(A
AnsT→A:rowSwap(A,1,dim(A
```

Comment: This will throw an error when you try to store a matrix to the real variable A.

Comment: In addition, it doesn't take input in the right format, which should be space-separated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 13 bytes

```
q~]W%3/zSf*N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%5DW%253%2FzSf*N*&input=1%202%203%0A4%205%206%0A7%208%209)

CJam is newer than this challenge. This solution is very similar to the GolfScript one.

#### Explanation

```
q~   e# Read input and evaluate, pushing all 9 numbers on the stack.
]    e# Wrap them in an array.
W%   e# Reverse it - this performs a 180° rotation.
3/   e# Split into rows of length 3.
z    e# Transpose.
Sf*  e# Join integers in each row with spaces.
N*   e# Join the rows with linefeeds.
```

If there was no constraint on 3x3 inputs, we could either compute the line width with a square root:

```
q~]W%_,mQ/zSf*N*
```

Or we could perform the anti-diagonal transpose as vertical flip, transpose, vertical flip (like my Mathematica answer does):

```
qN/Sf/W%zW%Sf*N*
```

In either case, we'd have 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
write(scan()[rep(9:7,e=3)-3*0:2],1,3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qvbKhgpGAMhCYKpgoQtjIQmwKxEVDMCChmrGDIBVUGUmSmYK5goWAJVGYJZBsD2aZAOXOgnOH/8qLMklSN4uTEPA3N6KLUAg1LK3OdVFtjTV1jLQMro1gdQx1jzf9gs7jApnGB2f8B)

Simply changes the order of the elements of the input vector.

Well, actually a basic approach is shorter:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
write(matrix(rev(scan()),3,,T),1,3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCoAwFEP3nuJDlxb@8vut2nt4AREHBx2qqLevsUoIhOSRXKxQIIUaivRlC0c4oAvolMT82Au11FFPCVhCVuSIrcMm5crLMbt1PPJyuzyfbp/GzXnPyjx4FlZf6pOpT6Y@lQc)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 (or 3) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|€#øRí»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5lHTGuXDO4IOrz20@/9/QwUjBWMuEwVTBTMucwULBUsA)

With less strict I/O rules it would be 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead, with I/O being a 3x3 matrix of integers:

```
øRí
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I6gw2v//4@ONtQx0jGO1Yk20THVMQPS5joWOpaxsQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
         #  e.g. input = "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9"
|        # Take all input-lines as a list of strings
         #  STACK: ["1 2 3","4 5 6","7 8 9"]
 €#      # Split each line by spaces
         #  STACK: [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
   ø     # Zip the matrix, swapping rows with columns
         #  STACK: [["1","4","7"],["2","5","8"],["3","6","9"]]
    R    # Reverse the order of rows in the matrix
         #  STACK: [["3","6","9"],["2","5","8"],["1","4","7"]]
     í   # Reverse each row of the matrix
         #  STACK: [["9","6","3"],["8","5","2"],["7","4","1"]]
      »  # Join each row by spaces, and then everything by newlines
         #  STACK: "9 6 3\n8 5 2\n7 4 1"
         # (after which it is output implicitly)
```

Here some alternatives with different order of operations:

```
øíR
Ríø
íRø
íøí
RøR
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṚZṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzllRQPz////oaEMdBSMdBeNYHYVoEx0FUx0FMxDTXEfBQkfBMjYWAA)

Uses Python list format for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
yÔÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=t224&code=edTU&footer=Vm24tw&input=IjEgMiAzCjQgNSA2CjcgOCA5Ig)

```
yÔÔ     :Implicit input of 2D array
y       :Transpose
 Ô      :Reverse rows
  Ô     :Reverse array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 27 bytes

```
[ anti-flip simple-table. ]
```

`anti-flip` postdates build 1525, the one TIO uses, so here's a picture of running this in Factor's REPL:

[image]

Note that in a standard output context, `simple-table.` outputs its elements with spaces in between. In the REPL, it's a little fancier.

Answer (score 1):

## [flax](https://github.com/Pygamer0/flax), 2 bytes

```
Ṙ∝
```

ATO doesn't have the lastest commit of flax (because I keep discovering bugs). So here is an image of it in action:
[image: flax repl]

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 103 bytes

Expects string input and outputs string

```
s=>(s=s.split`
`.map(x=>x.split` `))[0].map((_,c)=>s.map((_,r)=>s[2-r][2-c])).map(x=>x.join` `).join`
`
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>(s=s.split`
`.map(x=>x.split` `))[0].map((_,c)=>s.map((_,r)=>s[2-r][2-c])).map(x=>x.join` `).join`
`

;[
`1 2 3
3 4 5
1 2 3`,
`1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9`
].forEach(x=>console.log(f(x)))
```

## JavaScript, 45 bytes

Expects 2D array input and outputs 2D array

```
m=>m[0].map((_,c)=>m.map((_,r)=>m[2-r][2-c]))
```

Try it:

```js
f=m=>m[0].map((_,c)=>m.map((_,r)=>m[2-r][2-c]))

;[
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3]
  ],
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
].forEach(x=>console.log(JSON.stringify(f(x))))
```